# Can I add buttons to a TabbedPage navigation bar?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

My Xamarin app centers around a TabbedPage, which at the moment doesn't render a Navigation bar on appearing due to this code:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
    base.OnAppearing();
}
```

I have this code because when the TabbedPage renders with a navigation bar, the bar is placed above the tabs and takes up a lot more screen real estate than I would like:
[image]

With the code active, it doesn't render the bar and the tabs are the desired size:
[image]

My desired outcome is to combine the two, and have buttons (not necessarily the arrows as shown in the image) that are aligned with the tabs and not above them. This is what I would like it to look like:
[image]

Here is the code behind the TabbedPage (all in C# unfortunately as I need the pages constructed with certain data).

```
public TabbedPage(SelectedLocation selectedLocation, Login login)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.selectedLocation = selectedLocation;
    this.login = login;
    var page1 = new FirstPage(selectedLocation, login);
    page1.IconImageSource = "ic_one.png";
    page1.Title = "Page1";
    var page2= new SecondPage(selectedLocation, login);
    page2.IconImageSource = "ic_two.png";
    page2.Title = "Page2";
    var page 3 = new ThirdPage(selectedLocation, login);
    page3.IconImageSource = "ic_three.png";
    page3.Title = "Page3";
    var page4 = new FourthPage(selectedLocation, login);
    page4.IconImageSource = "ic_four.png";
    page4.Title = "Page4";
    Children.Add(page1);
    Children.Add(page2);
    Children.Add(page3);
    Children.Add(page4);
}

protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
    base.OnAppearing();
}
```

I've heard that I may need a custom renderer to accomplish this? Or is there some way that I can alter the margins of the tab view to fit buttons in on either side?

Comment: Navigationbar and Tabbar are two different things. I don't think you can combine 
them into one.

Comment: I have issues with this design-wise; Those buttons are very misleading and tightly-placed for a user, they will missclick several times on the side tab buttons instead of the back and forward buttons. Are you sure this is good UX?